# leaflet maps zoom at the current mouse position

Tags: zooming, leaflet, mouse-position

I would like to zoom into the mouseposition with leaflet maps. Like a doubleclick on the map. 
Usually the zoom uses the center of the map, but I would like to zoom around the mousepos..

Answer (score 4):

Per default the map behaves exactly as you want. The option `scrollWheelZoom` is set to `true` per default which means it will zoom in on the position of where your mouse is at that time. If you use `'scrollWheelZoom': 'center'`, it will zoom to the center of the current map bounds. `'scrollWheelZoom': false` will disable the scrollwheel entirely. See the documentation: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-scrollwheelzoom

If your map behaves differently it must mean that your map's `scrollWheelZoom` options is set to `center`; But your saying 'usually' which i'm finding very curious since it would mean your map behaves differently everytime you zoom, that would be very odd.

Here's a Plunker demonstration of all three behaviors: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhHqK9?p=preview